# Can a mesh be used as a guide for hair?

Tags: mesh, hair

I'm my experiments with hair in the particles feature, I've seen certain ways one can shape hair, such as the manual and tedious usage of the particle edit mode functions, to using bezier curves as hair guides.

While curves do make the process significantly easier, it still seems limited. From what I've tried, it makes the hair take on a noodle-like shape. This got me wondering. If a curve could be used as a way to guide hair into a desired shape, why not a mesh?

Naturally, I tried to recreate the steps of using a curve guide, but with a mesh, but nothing happened. Is it not possible, or am I just not doing it correctly?

To clarify, the curve guide method is to create a curve, enable the curve's force field physics and set it to curve guide.

Running 2.8

Comment: Try using Vertex Groups options (like Density) in the Particle System's settings.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How am I meant to use those options? And on what? The emitter? The mesh guide? Something else? And how does density, or any other vertex group setting work as a guide?

Answer (score 1):

I love curves. To make it look less noodle like, go to the curve circle and edit the shape of it. To give it more of a stand like appearance just copy some of the vertices in the circle detached from the original circle. It turns out beautifully, but don't be afraid to copy a lot of detached vertices. Also, another thing is the curve. That is what makes it thick and thin. I hope this was helpful.